# Solr requests hang when started via python subprocess

Tags: python, solr

I am attempting to start a solr instance locally in my test code in order for my app to be able to write to it successfully.

I start solr the following way:

```
f = open('output.log', 'w')
subprocess.Popen('java -jar start.jar --daemon')
```

Then in my test code I assure that I clean solr documents before each run:

```
def clean_solr():
    query = '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>'
    update_url = 'http://localhost/solr/update?stream.body={}'.format(query)
    requests.get(update_url)
```

my problem is that every once in a while, during the `requests` get operation, it hangs for some reason... I pinpointed where it hanged by placing `print` statements before and after the `requests` call... Did anyone experience something similar before or have any idea why it hangs?

I am guessing it's related to the way I start solr through python given the hanging does not occur when I start solr in the terminal and have my tests point to it...

Comment: Have you checked the Solr logs for any signs of why it's failing?

Comment: yep, it gets stuck here:

Feb 27, 2017 5:18:07 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 deleteAll
INFO: [search-1] REMOVING ALL DOCUMENTS FROM INDEX

Comment: I can also notice sometimes when it doesn't get stuck, it shows additional info with the delete statement etc... so clearly it gets stuck at the moment of deletion, but no idea why